# Can't enable OTB provider in QGIS 3.22.11?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

How can I activate Orfeo ToolBox in QGIS 3.22.11 (LTR)?

I enabled the plugin and checked the provider from processing but I don't find the check button in OTB provider :
[image]

Are there any suggestions to fix that issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same version of QGIS, also missing the Activate checkbox in OTB provider. Entering the correct details for 'OTB application folder' and 'OTB folder' was sufficient to activate OTB, checkbox not needed.

Comment: Where can I find the folder?

Comment: @belhichb - the QGIS plugin for OTB requires the OTB application to be downloaded and installed from https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/. Then the 'OTB folder' is the top folder for the OTB application and the 'OTB application folder' is below the top OTB folder at /lib/otb/applications.